# Request/Response Javascript from async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, websocket, async-await, rxjs

I have this piece of code which I'm not terribly unhappy with, but was wondering how to convert to reactive paradigm and not using async/await coming in ES7 (since I know how to do that, I think).
Excuse the comments in the code, I usually take them out once debugging is done. I am using async.js hoping it would bring me things like async/await but no. Also if anybody knows of a good similar CountDownLatch impl in javascript I would be interested to hear about it.

```js
document.getElementById('submitLoginBtn').addEventListener("click", function () {
        var rqid = nextReqId();
        async.series([
            function(callback) {
                console.log("Generating password for reqid: " + rqid);
                genPartOfRequest(callback);
            },
            function(callback) {
                console.log("Adding listener for " + msg_LogonResponse + " and reqid: " + rqid);
                mHandler.addListener(msg_LogonResponse, rqid, function(msg) {
                    console.log("Listener callback called for " + msg_LogonResponse + " and reqid: " + rqid);
                    if (isOk(msg)) {
                        postLogin(msg);
                    }
                    callback(null);
                });
                console.log("Sending logon request for " + msg_LogonRequest + " and reqid: " + rqid);
                logon(msg_LogonRequest, rqid);
            },
            function(callback) {
                console.log("Removing listener for " + msg_LogonResponse + " and reqid: " + rqid);
                mHandler.removeListener(msg_LogonResponse, rqid);
                callback(null);
            }
        ]);
    });
```

mHandler is a 'class' I created to insert listeners for particular responses the request should generate. I am using websockets.

Thanks
D

Comment: so is what you're saying , "the code works, but you think it could be better"?

Comment: `Excuse the comments in the code` - there are **no comments** in your code

Comment: I found this which looks excellent https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754   but not sure I understand it well enough to convert my code to what he is talking about.

Comment: Sorry, I meant console.log statements.

Comment: ` 
//Create Stream that does part the work
requestStream.subscribe(function(msg) {  
  var responseStream = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
  try {
     var resp = JSON.parse(msg);
     observer.onNext(resp);
  } catch () {
      observer.onError()
  }
  observer.completed();

  responseStream.subscribe(function(response) {
    postLogin();
  });
}
`

Comment: you can't post code in comments - try editing your question if you want to add more useful information